# Want to make the trasitions smooth of Navigation Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

Complete application is working fine but when it comes to transition of side drawer or we can say navigation menu it is not smooth. It make delay while opening and closing.
Here is my main activity code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);


    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

private void loadHomeFragment() {
    selectNavMenu();

    setToolbarTitle();

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        return;
    }

    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    drawer.closeDrawers();

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;

        case 1:
            HealthFragment healthFragment = new HealthFragment();
            return healthFragment;

        case 2:
            PinFragment pinFragment = new PinFragment();
            return pinFragment;

        case 3:
            SupportFragment supportFragment = new SupportFragment();
            return supportFragment;

        case 4:
            FeedbackFragment feedbackFragment = new FeedbackFragment();
            return feedbackFragment;

        case 5:
            FAQsFragment faQsFragment = new FAQsFragment();
            return faQsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_health:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HEALTH;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_pin:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PIN;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_support:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SUPPORT;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_feedback:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_FEEDBACK;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_faqs:
                    navItemIndex = 5;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_FAQS;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_chat:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_rate:
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sega.sonicdash");
                    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

                    goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    try {
                        startActivity(goToMarket);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sega.sonicdash")));
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_aboutus:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;


                case R.id.nav_share:
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }


            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            /* My edits */

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {

        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I am switching fragments in navigation menu. How to make these transitions of menu in and out smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not overload the app during the animations, do the hard work either in advance or after the animations.

For example: after the user selects the desired fragment, you have at first close the drawer and after animation ends launch the fragment transaction.
The closing animation can be speeded up if you know that after the closure, transaction should start.